# Suggest feature of elasticsearch in Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to use the suggest feature of elastic search in Nest ?  I cannot find it in the current documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation has a hard time keeping up with the fast pace the elasticsearch core team are pushing features!

Your best bet for the time being is to look at the unit tests:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/tree/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/suggest/CompletionSuggestTests.cs

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/tree/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/suggest/PhraseSuggestTests.cs

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/tree/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/suggest/TermSuggestTests.cs

Comment: As you said it changes a lot. Here is the new URL: [link](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/tree/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/suggest)

Comment: Changed again ?

Answer (score 1):

What i did when feature was missing it was cloning sources, creating branch, then i have added implementation and then i did pull request. So now i have that feature :)

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST